# Using R's `get()` function, while qualifying with the package

Tags: r, function, package

I'd like to assign a function to variable, using a string.  The `get()` function in the `base` package does *almost* exactly what I want.  For example,

```
valueReadFromFile <- "median"
ds <- data.frame(X=rnorm(10), Y=rnorm(10))
dynamicFunction <- get(valueReadFromFile)
dynamicFunction(ds$X) #Returns the variable's median.
```

However, I want to qualify the function with its package, so that I don't have to worry about (a) loading the function's package with `library()`, or (b) calling the wrong function in a different package.

Is there a robust, programmatic way I can qualify a function's name with its package using `get()` (or some similar function)?  The following code doesn't work, presumably because `get()` doesn't know how to interpret the package name before the `::`.

```
require(scales) #This package has functions called `alpha()` and `rescale()`
require(psych) #This package also has functions called `alpha()` and `rescale()`

dynamicFunction1 <- get("scales::alpha")
dynamicFunction2 <- get("psych::alpha")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also call `::` directly with character values, or `getExportedValue`, which `::` uses internally

eg

```
dynamicFunction1 <- `::`('scales', 'alpha')
dynamicFunction2 <- `::`('psych', 'alpha')
```

or

```
dynamicFunction1 <-  getExportedValue('scales', 'alpha')
dynamicFunction2 <-  getExportedValue('psych', 'alpha')
```

Comment: Thanks @mnel.  It's funny how the first approach avoids `get()` entirely.  I think I'll use the first way.  I'm guessing it might be a tad more robust because it passes the package and function name through `substitute()`.  But's that's a very uninformed guess.

Comment: I'm glad you included that second approach.  That `substitute()` call inside `::` meant I couldn't directly pass variables, but this works:

`x_label_split <- strsplit("scales::comma", split="::")[[1]]`;

`getExportedValue(x_label_split[1], x_label_split[2])`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dynamicFunction1 <- get("alpha", envir=as.environment("package:scales"))
dynamicFunction2 <- get("alpha", as.environment("package:psych"))
```

A matter of terminology: I would not call `dynamicFunction1` a "variable" but rather a "name". There is not really a formal class of object named "variable" but I usually see that term used for data-objects whereas "names" are language objects.

Comment: Thanks @IShouldBuyABoat.  That avoids the collisions I was worried about, but works only if the package was already loaded. ...assuming I'm not making a mistake.

Comment: Well, I was taking your lead in loading the package. If you want to incorporate a test for the loaded status at the same time as doing the load if it is installed then the usual code is `if(require(pkg)){do_something()}`

Comment: Good point, @IShouldBuyABoat. I'll look at the design again and consider if this is a better fit.  I like what you're saying --that I need to consider if I want the function's package (A) loaded into the environment if it's not already, or (B) hidden from the global environment.